# Android execute action on enter press in edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext, keypress

I'm trying to execute an action, a search, after the user press enter while typing in an edit text. Its not working. The codes are:

```
edtSearch.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                    System.out.println("test");
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }});
```

The XML for edittext,

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtSearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" >
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
```

Any idea why its not working.

Answer (score -1):

You should set input type and IME options, for example like this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone">`
```

and inside your activity set OnEditorActionListener to EditText:

```
edit.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                    Log.i(TAG,v.getText().toString());
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```